# For each loop takes more time to complete

Tags: c#, .net

I have a foreach on a list. List length will be huge always like 200K or so.

When i iterate through the list in foreach, the logic within the foreach will be dealing with another collection which is also will be around 1 million items in the list. For each iteration, the collection will be filtered and it needs to update on property and return the collection as it is. But by doing this, the process never gets completed.

```
foreach(var list in iterationlist)
{
  var filteredCollections = collection.where(a=>a.name==list.name);
   filteredCollections.foreach(x=>{x.city="xxxx";});
}
```

What are the ways to make this logic faster ? Currently this implementation takes more than 3 hours but not completing yet

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of a list.  The average retrieval time for a list is N/2 while the dictionary uses a binary hash which has a retrieval time of Log2(N).  Do list of one million items will take an average of 500,000 iterations while a dictionary will take only 20 seeks.

Comment: @jdweng , you asking me to convert the collection inside foreach loop to dictionary type , am I right ? Still the outer loop will iterate for huge length ? Is there a way to speed that up ?

Comment: @philipxy , apologies I am not getting your last point you meant to sort input output relationship, can you please elaborate a bit on that ?

Comment: I meant, Please tell us in what way or ways is your output a function of your input. Because that will  determine appropriate data structures & algorithms. But focusing on how the output is a function of the input before you start thinking about data structures & algorithms is part of determining appropriate data structures & algorithms. Hence 'You do not "need" to iterate. You need to update appropriate elements according to input.' And why I didn't even say "the kind or kinds of filtering & updating" you want to do.

Comment: No.  You can still have your list.  The Dictionary doesn't copy the existing data.  Instead it just creates keys and pointers to existing values into your current list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Lookup` (it's similar to `Dictionary<key, List<value>>`):

```
var lookup = collection.ToLookup(a => a.name);

foreach (var list in iterationlist)
    foreach (var x in lookup[list.name])
        x.city="xxxx";
```

---

Another option is to hash the names:

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(iterationlist.Select(x => x.name));

foreach (var x in collection)
    if (names.Contains(x.name))
        x.city="xxxx";
```